# How to hide the context menu of Ribbon Control

Tags: .net, wpf, contextmenu, ribbon

I need to hide the context menu of Ribbon Control

[image: Context Menu Appearing]

I tried

```
<Ribbon.ContextMenu><ContextMenu Visibility="Hidden"></ContextMenu></Ribbon.ContextMenu>
```

This did the job upto some extent. ie it disables context menu when right clicked on empty space. But when i right click on a ribbon button, still the context menu appears. How can i disable this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ribbon is a ribbon, you should not disable its features. If your "ribbon" really looks like this, consider using toolbars.

That being said, you can disable context menus by setting them to null on all controls on all levels of hierarchy:

```
<Ribbon ContextMenu="{x:Null}">
    <RibbonTab Header="abc" ContextMenu="{x:Null}">
        <RibbonGroup Header="abc" ContextMenu="{x:Null}">
            <RibbonButton Content="abc" ContextMenu="{x:Null}"/>
        </RibbonGroup>
    </RibbonTab>
</Ribbon>
```

Comment: Don't agree with "you should not disable its features" because not all futures allways needed, but you saved me a lot of time with ContextMenu="{x:Null}". Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can add a style to the app.xaml Under <Application.Resources> for all of your ribbon items. See the example below.

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ContextMenu x:Key="HiddenContextMenu" Visibility="Hidden"/>
    <Style TargetType="Ribbon">
        <Setter Property="Ribbon.ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource HiddenContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="RibbonTab">
        <Setter Property="RibbonTab.ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource HiddenContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="RibbonGroup">
        <Setter Property="RibbonGroup.ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource HiddenContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="RibbonButton">
        <Setter Property="RibbonButton.ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource HiddenContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="RibbonRadioButton">
        <Setter Property="RibbonRadioButton.ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource HiddenContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="RibbonTextBox">
        <Setter Property="RibbonTextBox.ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource HiddenContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="RibbonComboBox">
        <Setter Property="RibbonComboBox.ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource HiddenContextMenu}"/>
    </Style>
</Application.Resources>
```